# Child grid checkbox checked event not getting fired when unchecked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a Nested grid and check box in parent and child grid. There is a main checkbox at parent grid header to select all data. Then there is another check box against parent row and third check box against every child row.
first two checkboxes and events are working fine. 
Issue is with child grid checkbox. when I check the checkbox the event gets fired as expected. But when the checkbox is unchecked the event doesn't get fired. instead it is just posting back. 
Code is as below.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grdmaster" runat="server" SkinID="GridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ProjectNo" HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Height="35px" OnRowDataBound ="grdmaster_RowDataBound" >
                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Forging">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus1.png" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlforginfo" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                                <asp:GridView ID ="gvforgmst" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  CssClass="ChildGrid" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" SkinID="GridView">
                                    <Columns>                                  
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ForgingNo" HeaderText="Forging No" />
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ProductType" HeaderText="Product" /> 
                                        <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Height="35px">

                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkviewforg" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkviewforg_CheckedChanged" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="True" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>                                                                          
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                         
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ProjectNo" DataField="ProjectNo" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CustomerName" DataField="CustomerName" />                       
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="GradCode" DataField="GradCode" />
                    <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Height="35px">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>






protected void chkviewforg_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int cnt = 0;
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)grdmaster.HeaderRow.Cells[4].FindControl("chkAll");
        for (int i = 0; i < grdmaster.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridView gvforgmst = (GridView)grdmaster.Rows[i].FindControl("gvforgmst");

            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)grdmaster.Rows[i]
                         .Cells[4].FindControl("chk");
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvforgmst.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkviewforg = ((CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkviewforg"));

                if (chkviewforg.Checked)
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }

            if (gvforgmst.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (cnt == gvforgmst.Rows.Count)
                {
                    chk.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    chk.Checked = false;
                    chkAll.Checked = false;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you try giving handler OnCheckedChanged at ItemDataBound?

Comment: I've not used ItemDataBound event. Could you please explain how to do it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx